# Regex for QString::split() for two float numbers

Tags: regex, qt, qstring

I have the QString line like this "567\n1.23456 2.34567\n1.23456 2.34"

And I want only "whole" float numbers only between \n characters.

I need QStringList after `split()` that contains only this float numbers. `QString::split()` can use RegEx so maybe I can use som regex here.

i tried `QStringList myList = QString("56\n1.12345 2.34567\n1.23456 2.34").split('\n')` that returns me ["1.2345 2.34567"] so i need split this again to ["1.23456"] and ["2.34567"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt documentation for [QString::split](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) has your answer

```
QString str;
QStringList list;
str = "Some  text\n\twith  strange whitespace.";
list = str.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+"));
// list: [ "Some", "text", "with", "strange", "whitespace." ]
```

Comment: yes and after split i have 56, 1.12345 2.34567 1.23456 2.34, but i only need float numbers surrounded by "\n" characters.

Comment: Then use split twice ... once using QChar('\n'), then using QChar(' ') or QRegularExpression("\\s+") depending on how reliable the whitespace between the floats is.

Answer (score 0):

this regex `\d+(\.\d+)?` will give you any float/int number!

Answer (score 0):

You should split at `QRegularExpression("\\s+")`. `\s` means whitespace (which includes both =space and `\n`=newline), `+` means one or more, and you need to escape the backslash.